# does inherited class can access base class

Tags: c#, oop

If I have `ThumbPhoto` entity which inherits `Photo` entity and Photo entity inherits `Entity<int>` is it enough to use

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo
```

or should I use

> `public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo, Entity<int>`

Comment: Why don't you try the two out and see for yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, so no.

That aside though, this:

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo
```

Means that you'll have access to the `Entity` methods/properties because of

```
public class Photo : Entity<int>
```

This principle works however deep your inheritance gets.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#. You cannot inherit from more than one class. However hierarchical inheritance is fine. So it is ok to write:

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo
```

and you also derive from `Entity<int>`

Answer (score 1):

The first is sufficient.

The base classes or interfaces from your base class are automatically inherited.

In fact is `Entity` isn't an interface, the later isn't even valid, as you can only specify a single base class in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo
```

Above is an option and sufficient, because nothing would be gained if you could also include `Entity<int>` assumping `Photo` is derived from `Entity<int>`

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo, Entity<int>
```

Above is example of *multiple inheritance* which is *not* supported in C#

---

Do not confuse this with multiple interface implementation, which is supported:

```
public class ThumbnailPhoto : Photo, IEntity, IAmAnInterface
```